# DSE chair rights

Tags: work-environment, resignation, job-change, offices

can I keep a chair that was made specifically  for me at my previous job,  the chair is at my home address and  is over 7 years old

Comment: what does DSE mean in your question title?

Comment: Are the any labels/numbers on the chair that would show that it is being counted as part of inventory?

Comment: It isn't about "rights", it's about employer policy and practice.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki DSE (Display Screen Equipment) appears to be a British ergonomics standard for people who work with computers, etc.  https://www.hse.gov.uk/msd/dse/

Comment: "previous job", you mean, you've already kept the chair past your employment and is wondering if you can keep it? How long ago did you leave? What made you think they even knew you have this chair of theirs after this period?

Answer (score 8):

Ask your employer.

If you have good to great relation it can be as simple as "Hey, I still got this 7 years old made for me chair, it has no real market value but helps with me [DSE needs here], can I keep it, or do you want me to send it back?".

If your relation is less than stellar and you want to increase your chances, make the ask a bit more cheeky, something along the lines:

> Hey, I have this old chair in the office, it was made specifically for
> my needs over 7 years ago, so I doubt it has any resell value, but it
> still helps with me [insert DSE needs]. Would it be possible for me to
> keep it instead of sending it back so it rots in storage?
>
> If not and you want it instead, please provide postage and packaging
> for it, here's quote: [insert highest quote you can find online that's
> still reasonable] and I can get this sorted asap, just let me know.

Should be pretty effective, you convey that the chair has no value for them, that it will cost them money to receive and then deal with it (skips tend to charge for large items) and that it will be a nice thing to let you keep it as a bonus. Win-win really.

You could even offer to donate some amount of money to charity of their choice if they let you keep it, depends on how strongly do you expect a mostly-petty "no, send it back".

Comment: You could also offer to buy it off them (which shows willing) - but given that the book value will be close to zero they're likely to decide that it's not worth the accounting faff trying to sell it to you, and just let you keep it for free.

Comment: @Gh0stFish yeah that's why I went the charitable donation route instead, at least they get a tiny writeoff of it at least, not an accounting hassle for 5$ chair.

Comment: @Gh0stFish Yep. And some employers will sell it to you, and just chuck the money into petty cash, often held at reception.

Answer (score 1):

I would either just keep it until asked about it. Or offer to buy it.

You're under no obligation to track their assets, they should have staff paid to do that for them. So really I would only offer to buy it if I was actually asked about it.

Comment: My feeling exactly. It is easier to ask forgiveness than to ask permission.  If they ask about it, you can say, "Oh, that thing.  I'm not 100% sure what happened to that." (Truthful because you don't recall every time it was used for the last N years.)

Comment: @user1683793 that's really pushing the definition of "truth" past reasonable limits, op is literally asking online about the chair. Granted, this is not some great crime with consequences for lying, but people do quickly learn who is upfront and honest, and who is happy to "forget" when it benefits them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really focused on "rights", meaning legalities... My understanding is that, in the US, if they don't ask about it for 7 years or so it becomes "abandoned property" and you can do with it as you see fit. Xerox failed to reclaim a telecopier (how's that for ancient technology; analog fax machine) from my father's office when the lease ended; he stuck it in a closet in case they asked, they never did, it eventually got thrown out.

(I considered trying to create a PC driver for it, generating the appropriately timed analog modem tones, but decided not to be ridiculous.)